# Domain user locks everyday, how to find out what causes this issue?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-accounts

One user in your organization gets locked out everyday, it starts as outlook ask for password and the user is already locked.
We have email installed on smartphones and also we use outlook software.

I think is must be connected to Outlook software, which may not saving new credentials, not updating old password to current password.
Also we have email in smartphones, which may be causing problem..

What is easy way to start investigating ? What do you recommend?
i.e Event Manager

Using Office c2r 2019 version currently.

Comment: We see this frequently in our organization. When a user changes their Active Directory password, they are also reminded to enter the new password in their cellphone mail app - most of the time, repeated lockouts like this turn out to be because they forgot to do so, or there's a problem with their cellphone and the new password isn't remembered.

Comment: Also, search your domain controller(s) for Security audit event ID 4740 around the time the account lock-out occurred.  Note: Event ID 4740 is an Informational "Audit Success" event. If you're lucky, the offending computer system _may_ be listed in the "Caller Computer Name" of the event data.  Either force the user to logout of that system, or reboot the system.

Comment: Do you mean locked in outlook? If so, could you provide a screenshot about it? (In order to avoid the disclosure of your privacy, please remember to hide your personal information).

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided?

Comment: I found out what was the problem, I cleared hidden credentials.  
Method: Clear Network Saved Credentials Using the Run Command
Press the Windows key + R together to open the Run box. Type the following command and hit Enter. Delete saved credential and reboot.
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method:** Clear Network Saved Credentials Using the Run Command Press the Windows key + R together to open the Run box. Type the following command and hit Enter. Delete saved credential and reboot.

rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr

update 14.06.22
the issue continued after some days. Reinstalled Windows but the user still locks, but be server side fault.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance the password changed, but they are logged in or the creds are a part of a service account or something.
Below is a link to some suggestions from Microsoft. At the bottom of the page is a link to a tool to help you troubleshoot lockouts (from Microsoft).

In general, you need to figure out which domain controller handled the request. From there, you can determine where the request came from (which machine). Then you need to investigate that machine and see what is causing the problem. I hope this is enough. Good luck -

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23497.active-directory-troubleshooting-frequent-account-lockout.aspx

Comment: You really should quote and cite the relevant information from external websites.